# sql - return customers that visit the place that sells their favourite drink

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to sql.

I have the follow db tables:

**Frequents:**

| Customer | DrinkKiosk |
| --- | --- |
| Stu | Bar omarma |
| David | Jakes Bar |
| Jim | Bar omarma |
| Steve | Tims Bar |

**Likes:**

| Title | Customer | Postcode | Favourite |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mr | Stu | ghy785 | Wiskey |
| Mr | David | ghy785 | Beer |
| Mr | Jim | ghy789 | Wiskey |
| Mr | Steve | ghy781 | Smoothie |

**Sells:**

| DrinkKiosk | Drink | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bar omarma | Wiskey | 3.00 |
| Jakes Bar | Beer | 2.00 |
| The Swan | Smoothie | 1.00 |
| Tims Bar | Blue lagoon | 2.80 |
| The Oak | water | 3.10 |

I'm trying to create a query that returns a table of customers and the DrinkKiosk, where the customer frequents the kiosk that happens to sell their favourite drink.

**Result:**

| Customer | DrinkKiosk |
| --- | --- |
| Stu | Bar omarma |
| David | Jakes Bar |
| Jim | Bar omarma |

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question

Comment: select..from likes join frequents..join sells

Comment: @WhatTheWhat check the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uLPPE1DoKjKYBoSXfKahJN/19

Comment: thanks alot @ErgestBasha, please post as answer and I'll accept

Comment: @WhatTheWhat this question doesn't accept answers because is closed . I feel like you deserved an answer for the effort showed on editing the question

Comment: @ErgestBasha you are a kind soul, and you've saved my ass! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ErgestBasha for the following answer:

```
select l.Customer,
       s.DrinkKiosk
from likes l
    inner join sells s
        on s.Drink = l.Favourite
    inner join frequents f
        on s.DrinkKiosk = f.DrinkKiosk
group by l.Customer,
         s.DrinkKiosk;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).